# How to send commands to my program directly from Windwos CMD?

Tags: java, c#, windows, cmd

I would like my program to receive commands like java compiler does:

**CMD Input**

```
java -version
```

**CMD Output**

> java version "1.8.0_91"
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b14)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode, sharing)

So this is how I expect my program should work:

**CMD Input**

```
MyProgamName -MyFunction
```

**CMD Output**

> Output generated by my program

Comment: I know how to add my program to system variables, I don't know how to write program, that can be accepted by cmd.

Comment: Could you provide an example? A console app can always be run via command prompt.

Comment: I open cmd and enter: myProgramm, after, that I should have ability to enter my own predefined commands(cmd should recognize them), that does actions, that I have programmed myProgramm to do.

Comment: Either put your program file into a location which is in the path or put its location into the path!

Comment: Done that, how do I define commands, that cmd accepts ?

Comment: Those sound like command parameters. Could you post an *actual line* that shows what you are thinking?

Comment: To be more specific, what about command line parameters do you not understand?

Comment: I don't know how to make cmd accept my arguments, that triggers functions in my program

Comment: Ok.... I edited a ridiculously simple example into my program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously you can always just execute the program from its working directory.

To execute it from *other* places, you have to add the directory to the PATH environment variable. You can get there by (my steps from Windows 7):

1. Right click on "Computer" (or "My Computer")
2. Select "Properties"
3. Select "Advanced Settings"
4. Click on "Environment Variables" in the dialog
5. Append your directory to the end of the PATH variable

Now windows will find your exe if you use its name in a standard command prompt.

To using command line parameters to trigger functions, it varies wildly with your design. There *are* libraries out there to help with the parsing, but the simplest form would be this:

Command:

> myProg.exe --do-something

Program:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    switch (args[0])
    {
        case "--do-something":
           DoSomething();
           break;
    }
}
```

Not the most flexible, but like I said, you need to define what you are going to do with your command line parameters before you write the logic. Should be enough to get you started though.